# How to pre-fill correctly dropdown list in form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hey guys I try to update an element so I want to fill my form with values that exist. I success the task except for one dropdown list.
I do several requests because most of the data depends on other tables.
I've try to put each request into the callback of the previous one but I don't know why the dropdown doesn't fill correctly .

Here is my ngOnInit function

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.id_equipement = params['id']);

    this.equipementService
      .getEquipementById(this.id_equipement)
      .subscribe((data) =>{ this.equipement = data[0];
        console.log(this.equipement);
//Get the list for the dropdown       
this.equipementService.getEquipementRebond().pipe(first()).subscribe(eqs => {
                this.srv_rebond = eqs;
                console.log(this.srv_rebond);
                this.loginService.getLoginById(this.equipement.idLogin).subscribe ((login) =>{
                        this.login = login[0];
                        console.log(this.login);
                        if (this.equipement.idNode != null){
 //Get the element to pre-fill the dropdown             this.equipementService.getEquipementById(this.equipement.idNode).subscribe ((srv) => {
                                     this.serveur_rebond = srv[0];
                                     console.log(this.serveur_rebond.Nom);

                                this.editEqForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                                        nom:[this.equipement.Nom, [Validators.required]],
                                        ip:[this.equipement.IP, [Validators.required]],
                                        srv_rebond:[this.serveur_rebond.Nom, [Validators.required]],
                                        auth:[this.equipement.auth, [Validators.required]],
                                        login:[this.login.Login, [Validators.required]],
                                        pwd:[this.login.Password, [Validators.required]],
                                        connex: [this.equipement.Connex],
                                        rebond:[this.equipement.rebond],
                                        }); });
                        }else {
                                this.serveur_rebond.Nom = 'Aucun';

                                this.editEqForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                                        nom:[this.equipement.Nom, [Validators.required]],
                                        ip:[this.equipement.IP, [Validators.required]],
                                        srv_rebond:[this.serveur_rebond.Nom],
                                        auth:[this.equipement.auth, [Validators.required]],
                                        login:[this.login.Login, [Validators.required]],
                                        pwd:[this.login.Password, [Validators.required]],
                                        connex: [this.equipement.Connex],
                                        rebond:[this.equipement.rebond],
                                });
                        }
        });});});

  }
```

Here is a part of my form. Everything works but not the select formControlName="srv_rebond"

```html
 <form [formGroup]="editEqForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();">
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label>nom</label>
      <input formControlName="nom" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.nom.errors }" type=
        <div *ngIf="submitted&&f.nom?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.nom?.errors.required">
            Le nom d'équipement est requis!
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label>IP</label>
      <input formControlName="ip" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.ip.errors }" type="t
        <div *ngIf="submitted&&f.ip?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.ip?.errors.required">
            L'adresse IP est requise!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label>Serveur de rebond</label>
      <select formControlName="srv_rebond" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.srv_rebond.
        <option >Aucun</option>
        <option *ngFor="let srv of srv_rebond ">{{srv.Nom}}</option>
      </select>
              <div *ngIf="submitted && f.srv_rebond?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="f.srv_rebond?.errors.required">
                Le serveur de rebond est requis!
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <label>Authentification</label>
      <select formControlName="auth" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.auth.errors }" class="form-control" >
                <option selected>SSH</option>
                <option>Telnet</option>
                <option>Login</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.auth?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.auth?.errors.required">
             Le mode d'authentification est requis!
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I think the problem is into the ngOnInit function but I don't know where. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you log your `serveur_rebond` and your `srv_rebond` variables ?

Comment: console.log(this.serveur_rebond.Name) in if show me the value of the server name,
srv_rebond is an array of server name

Comment: I'm not asking you to explain to me what it displays, I'm asking you to do it and post it. Without the data, we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I did it in the last if :
console.log(this.serveur_rebond) : {id: 888, Nom: "MDM", IP: "1.1.1.1", auth: "SSH", idNode: null, …}
console.log(this.srv_rebond) : (23) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},]
2: {id: 43, Nom: "INEM2", IP: 172323742, auth: "Login", idNode: null, …}
3: {id: 439, Nom: "IMS_OMC", IP: 168098020, auth: "SSH", idNode: null, …}
4: {id: 780, Nom: "IMS_OMC4", IP: 168199701, auth: "SSH", idNode: null, …}
5: {id: 888, Nom: "MDM", IP: 172323709, auth: "SSH", idNode: null, …}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here assuming the rest of assignments are okay... You are missing `[value]` from your select options. If you want the value to be the property `Nom`, use it as value:

```
<option *ngFor="let srv of srv_rebond" [value]="srv.Nom">{{srv.Nom}}</option>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zykusf?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

*PS. For future questions, if you have an issue with a specific part in your code (in this case your form), you can omit the rest of the formcontrols (like I've done in stackblitz). It's much easier to read when the issue is presented clearly and not needing to read through a bunch of unrelated code.*

Answer (score 1):

I did not fully get the problem. But if it is that the select is not populated with data it could be a typo.

```
this.serveur_rebond = srv[0];
```

and

```
 <option *ngFor="let srv of srv_rebond ">{{srv.Nom}}</option>
```

or it could be that srv is and list and you take only the first element

Simplyfy the code and give better variables so you easier can see what wrong.

1. This call can be done separately. And give the member a better name:

   ```
   this.equipementService.getEquipementRebond().pipe(first())
    .subscribe(eqs =>{ 
       this.equipmentRebonds= eqs;
   });
   ```
2. add

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="editEqForm" *ngIf="editEqForm"
   ```
3. Change

   ```
    this.serveur_rebond = srv[0];
   ```

to something like:

```
 this.defaultEquipmentRebond = srv[0];
```

The init method should look something like:

1. getEquipementRebond
2. login call with nested call for default equipmentBond call. Then you     populated and create the default data in the reactive form

Comment: select is correctly populated, but I want the pre-fill the select with the server name related to my element. I correctly get the server name related it's one element of my select list but it's not used to prefill the select. I've the first item of the list "Aucun" always selected.

Comment: Remove the Aucun <option>. The default value should always be in the model

Comment: And you got a typo in srv_rebond:[this.serveur_rebond.Nom, [Validators.required]],

Comment: I've removed the aucun option and fill the this.serveur_rebond.Nom before to create the form. But I've still the same problem the first item of the dropdown is still selected. Is there any problems if Aucun option isn't part of this.srv_rebond array ??

Comment: I think you should not use an extra <option> when you use *ngFor on option

Comment: thank you for yours suggestions I'll simplify my code. I success with @AJT82 answer but I'll keep your too.